# Transaction broadcasts and block synchronization

Tags: transactions, block, synchronization

In the original publication about bitcoin, in section 5 it states that

> If two nodes broadcast different versions of the next block
>   simultaneously , some nodes may receive one or the other first. In
>   that case, they work on the first one they received but save the other
>   branch in case it becomes longer. The tie will be broken when the next
>   proof-of-work is found and one branch becomes longer;

the author then states

> New transaction broadcasts do not necessarily need to reach all nodes.
>   As long as they reach many nodes, they will get into a block before
>   long.

My question is: How do lost transactions "get into a block before long"? Are they constantly re-transmitted until they are 6 blocks deep and the proof of work has been completed? Is it possible that a transaction could be re-transmitted indefinitely, and it might never be put into a block that is fully synchronized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While implementation specific, transactions are only re-broadcasted by the bitcoin-qt client after every x minutes (30?) and only if it's not in the main chain yet. Once a block comes in that has the transaction, it'll stop transmitting. If a new chain is accepted later that doesn't have the transaction, it will start broadcasting again.

About transactions getting lost, [I already wrote an answer about that once](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9737/4358) :

> Most clients on the network have a transaction pool in their memory. The same basically applies to miners: they just dump the top 500KB (or some other value) transactions into a block, sorted by transaction fee (descending, of course). When there aren't many transactions, maybe because of a series of block in a short amount of time, it will be confirmed anyway.
>
> But to answer your actual question: yes, transactions (sort of) expire. When you send a transaction, it sends a `tx` frame to all connected peers. These peers store the transaction in their memory pools and tell all their connections that they have a new transaction. When those connections don't have it yet, they ask for it, and that's how a transaction spreads over the network.
>
> At some point every node in the network will have the transaction in their memory pool, and at that point it will no longer be sent over the network. Now when a user restarts their client, the memory pool is wiped, and the transaction is deleted from that computer. (Plus a few other ways to delete transactions from the pool)
>
> Because of that it's very unlikely for the transaction to be gone from the entire network, but in case it does happen: the reference client will automatically re-send the transaction every x hours(/minutes?) when it's still not confirmed.
>
> Oh, and I forgot the most important part: transactions on Bitcoin (`tx` frames in the protocol) don't have a 'time' field, which means that transaction expiration can't be a feature of Bitcoin.
>
> To summarize: yes, the transaction *can* expire, but that is really unlikely.

Comment: blockchain.info has some interesting information regarding [unconfirmed transactions](http://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) (Transactions waiting to be included in a block), and [orphaned blocks](http://blockchain.info/orphaned-blocks) (Valid blocks not part of the main bitcoin chain).