# bitcoin transaction stuck in limbo

Tags: multibit-hd

i tried sending a transaction using multibit hd, and its not even that i was trying to get cheesy on the fee, i just forgot to enter one in and now three days later ive lost 15 dollars from bitcoins losing value as my transaction is stuck at being viewed by 5 peers, but receiving no confirmations. after doing some research i seem to get mixed responses on what happens now, will the transaction get rejected and my coins be returned to me with mutibit hd, or do i have to do somthing proactive to get them back?

Comment: If it's been that long, you could try to import the key that controls the coins into another wallet and send a transaction that pays higher fees. Some wallets aren't smart enough to reverse a transaction if it doesn't get accepted by the network, but will recognize its no longer valid when it gets double spent by another transaction.

Answer (score 0):

MultiBit developer here. If you're using the latest version of MultiBit HD (0.2.0 at the time of writing) then your default would have been set to a reasonable level for the current network conditions of near full blocks. You can always set it higher if needed.

If your version is older and you haven't upgraded then the default fee will likely be too low to be accepted by a miner in the current conditions. It is likely to hang around until it is finally purged by all nodes from their mempools. This can take several days.

More information is here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9737/117 (as suggested by @StephenM347).